# PhantomJS Cookies

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, qunit, chutzpah

I'm trying to run some [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) test cases with [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and chutzpah console. I'm having difficulties communicate with the phantomJS cookies. My test case runs perfectly with the browser communicating with the but not with phantomJS as it gives an error with the cookie.

Does the phantomJS deals with Cookies in a different pattern than the other browsers? any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any code examples how you setup your Cookies for Phantomjs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got at least version 1.7 of PhantomJS? In the release notes it states:

> PhantomJS 1.7 "Blazing Star", was released on September 22, 2012. It
>   added module system support (modelled after CommonJS), **better
>   cookies handling**, and other small improvements.

http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version (v 1.9). I'm not able to retrieve cookies from chutzpah console. 

Debugging reveals that normal "document.cookie" method doesn't retrieve any cookies in chutzpha testing.

Is there a way to use phantom functions in chutzpah testing?